# different markup, but same Java code in wicket?

Tags: wicket, panels

I have a bunch of panels with different markup. I want to reuse the same Java class and work it out with variations.
In some panels some components are missing, but I don't want to make changes to my Java class to set the visibility of the component for each case. That can get a little messy. I want to reuse the same Java class, while my app doesn't break if there are missing components in the markup. 
So I think it comes down to this: 
1- can you add components to the panel class and then not use them in the mark up?

E.g:

```
Java
add(new Label("a","hello"));
add(new Label("b","hi"));
add(new Label("c","see ya"));
add(new Label("d","good bye"));

hello_1.hml
<span wicket:id="a">xxx</span>
<span wicket:id="b">xxx</span>
<span wicket:id="c">xxx</span>
<span wicket:id="d">xxx</span>

hello_2.hml<br>
<span wicket:id="a">xxx</span>
<div wicket:id="d">xxx</div>

hello_3.hml<br>
<div wicket:id="a">xxx</div>
<b wicket:id="c">xxx</b>

hello_4.hml<br>
<div wicket:id="a">xxx</div>
```

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question directly: no, the Java and the HTML side should match exactly.

However there's always a way around,  depending on the specific use case.

1. Make HTML elements invisible from CSS or a style attribute.
2. Use fragments to avoid rendering optional bits.
3. Use inheritance, with more feature-rich panels extending simple panels.
4. Make components invisible from Java code.

But I have to admit that the problem sounds somewhat suspicious, it is possible that with a more careful separation of components the whole issue can be avoided. But without knowing more about the system it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding the component in the Java hierarchy depending on the variation ?

if ("4".equals(getVariation()) {
 add(new ComponentA("a"));
}